# Using tf.data.Dataset to produce multi-input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I have a `dataset` (instance of tf.data.Dataset) which produces `image` as input and `label` as output. My model needs to get `[image, label]` as input and `label` as output. So how can I make this happen?

I've tried this:

```py
dataset = dataset.map(suit_IO)

def suit_IO(img, label):
  return [img, label], label
```

but gives this error:

> TypeError: Unsupported return value from function passed to Dataset.map(): ([<tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=(320, 320, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>], <tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested tuples, not a list :

```
def suit_IO(img, label):
  return (img, label), label
```